# Can I delete events.out.tfevents.XXXXXXXXXX.computer_name files from TENSORFLOW training folder

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am training faster_rcnn_inception module for object detection on custom dataset.
In training directory,we found folder called eval_0 and tensorflow generated events.out.tfevents.xxxxxx files.

**Training Directory structure as follows**

```
+training_dir
    +eval_0
     -events.out.tfevents.1542309785.instance-1  1.2GB
     -events.out.tfevents.1542367255.instance-1  5.3GB
     -events.out.tfevents.1542369886.instance-1  3.6GB
     -events.out.tfevents.1542624154.instance-1  31MB
     -events.out.tfevents.1543060258.instance-1  19MB
     -events.out.tfevents.1543066775.instance-2  1.6GB
 -events.out.tfevents.1542308099.instance-1  17MB
 -events.out.tfevents.1542308928.instance-1  17MB
 -events.out.tfevents.1542366369.instance-1  17MB
 -events.out.tfevents.1542369000.instance-1  17MB
 -events.out.tfevents.1542623262.instance-1  17MB
 -events.out.tfevents.1543064936.instance-2  17MB
 -events.out.tfevents.1543065796.instance-2  17MB
 -events.out.tfevents.1543065880.instance-2  17MB
 -model.ckpt-96004.data-00000-of-00001
 -model.ckpt-96004.data-00000-of-00001
 -model.ckpt-96004.index
 -model.ckpt-96004.meta
 -model.ckpt-96108.data-00000-of-00001
 -model.ckpt-96108.index
 -model.ckpt-96108.meta
```

As per my understanding, **tfevents** files in eval_0 folder are summery files of ***evaluation*** and tfevents files in **training_dir** are summery files of ***training***.

I have interrupted training process several times and continued from recent checkpoint.
I also understand restarting training process generates new tfevents files.

**My Questions as follows:**

- Why training **tfevents_files** have same size, but in case if
  **eval_0/tfevents_files size varies** ?
- Why interrupting training generates new **tfevents_file** in training
  folder, but same not observed in case of **eval_0**?
- Can I delete all **tfevents** files in **eval_0** except latest one? Does it
  affect on training or evolution history?

Comment: Hi Did you find answers to your questions?

Comment: Yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517857/can-i-delete-events-out-tfevents-xxxxxxxxxx-computer-name-files-from-training-fo